# How to Pass Generic T type values

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-4.0

I have an problem with this three classes.

In first class i'm extending for listview class for common method

In second class we put one method it's invoke by the 1st class

This is fine for above two classes but in my third class need to pass that T, M values. 
But i don't understand how to do this?

anybody help this issue?

Thank you

**1st Class**

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public UserControl uc { get; set; }
    internal MyLEvent<Type,Type> MyLEvnt  { get; set; }
    public MyListView()
    {
        PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyListView_PreviewKeyDown);
    }
    private void MyListView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         ListView view = sender as ListView;
         var item = view.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            string str = item.GetType().Name;
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                MyLEvnt.Method(item, "Delete");
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                MyLEvnt.Method(item, "Modify");
                uc.GetType().GetProperty("Update").SetValue(uc, 1, null);
                MethodInfo mi = uc.GetType().GetMethod("IClear");
                mi.Invoke(uc, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd Class**

```
 public class MyLEvent<T,M> where T : class where M : class
{
    private M manager;
    private T type;
    public MyLEvent()
    {

    }
    public object Method(object _view, string flog)
    {
        object retVal = null;
        type = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        manager = Activator.CreateInstance<M>();
        if (flog == "Modify")
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(M).GetMethod("getData");
            type = (T)method.Invoke(manager, new[] { _view });

        }
        else if (flog == "Set")
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(M).GetMethod("setDefault");
            retVal = method.Invoke(manager, new[] { _view });
        }
        else
        {
            if (MyMessage.askDelete() == true)
            {
                PropertyClass.Properties(_view, type, 'U');
                MethodInfo method = typeof(M).GetMethod("Delete");
                 retVal = method.Invoke(manager, new[] { type });
            }
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**3rd Class**

```
 public partial class SubASettings : UserControl
{
     public SubASettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MAILV.uc = this;
        MAILV.MyLEvnt = new MyLEvent<typeof(InvMail), MailManager>();
        Clear();
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: MAILV.MyLEvnt = new MyLEvent<InvMail, MailManager>();

Comment: Yes i did this but its show type conversion error "can not implicit to convert mailmanager to system.Type

Comment: What is `MailManager`?

Comment: @Szymon Irrelevant.  He declared his field as `MyLEvent<Type, Type>`, which is the fundamental problem.

Comment: MailManager is my Customer class, how to define the 1 class property of MLEvent<Type,Type> to call for 2 class. I want to pass any custom class type to 3rd class through 2nd class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a constraint to your **generic type** by declaring an **interface**:

```
public interface IManager 
{
    void getData();
    setDefault
    Delete
}
```

Define this constraint in declaration of second class which means that `M` type should implement `IManager` interface:

```
public class MyLEvent<T, M>
    where T : class
    where M : class, IManager
```

Then, you can invoke members of your class which defined in the interface:

```
public class MyLEvent<T, M>
    where T : class
    where M : class, IManager
{
    private M manager;

    public MyLEvent()
    {
        manager.Delete();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration:

```
public class MyLEvent<T,M> where T : class where M : class
{
...
}
```

...defines a **generic type** that is used to create **concrete types** when provided with the appropriate type parameters.  You cannot use generic types directly, you can only use them to create concrete types which can then be used.

For example, the `List<T>` generic type defines structure and code that can be used to create a variety of concrete types depending on the type parameter you use.  `List<string>` is a concrete type created from the `List<T>` generic type.

In the case of your `MyLEvent` generic, there are two type parameters: `T` and `M`.  You need to specify both of those to create a concrete type that can be used.

In your `MyListView` class you define the `MyLEvnt` field like this:

```
internal MyLEvent<Type,Type> MyLEvnt  { get; set; }
```

This defines the `MyLEvnt` field as an instance of the *concrete* type `MyLEvent<Type, Type>`.  Note that `Type` is a class that is used to access information about types.  In this usage it is *not* a way to avoid supplying a type parameter, it **is** a type parameter.

In your third class you then do this:

```
MAILV.MyLEvnt = new MyLEvent<typeof(InvMail), MailManager>();
```

Even when we take the `typeof()` out of it, this will fail because you are attempting to assign an instance of `MyLEvent<InvMail, MailManager>` to a field of type `MyLEvent<Type, Type>`.  These are different types, just as `List<string>` is different from `List<int>`.

You need to read the MSDN articles on [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/512aeb7t.aspx).  These explain the details of how generics work and give you a lot of examples of how to use them and why.

Comment: thank you. and i found one solution to resolve my issue. please see and tell me is its create any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for supporting. And i got one solution for this....

**This is my previous 1st class**

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
  public UserControl uc { get; set; }
  internal MyLEvent<Type,Type> MyLEvnt  { get; set; }
  public MyListView()
  {
    PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyListView_PreviewKeyDown);
  }
  private void MyListView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
  {
     ListView view = sender as ListView;
     var item = view.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        string str = item.GetType().Name;
        if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
        {
            MyLEvnt.Method(item, "Delete");
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            MyLEvnt.Method(item, "Modify");
            uc.GetType().GetProperty("Update").SetValue(uc, 1, null);
            MethodInfo mi = uc.GetType().GetMethod("IClear");
            mi.Invoke(uc, null);
        }
    }
 }
```

}

**After modified in my level....**

```
 public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public UserControl uc { get; set; }
    public object ML { get; set; }
    public MyListView()
    {
        PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyListView_PreviewKeyDown);
    }
    public void Methode<T,M>() where T : class where M : class
    {
        ListViewEvents<T, M> mn = new ListViewEvents<T, M>();
        ML = mn;
    }
    private void MyListView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         ListView view = sender as ListView;
         var item = view.SelectedItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            string str = item.GetType().Name;
            if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            {
                MethodInfo mi = ML.GetType().GetMethod("Method");
                mi.Invoke(ML,new[]{item,"Delete"});
                MethodInfo m = uc.GetType().GetMethod("IClear");
                m.Invoke(uc, null);
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                MethodInfo m = ML.GetType().GetMethod("Method");
                object ob = m.Invoke(ML, new[] { item, "Modify" });
                PropertyClass.Properties(uc, ob, 'U');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution is better working for me. But if is there any wrong with this 
please let me guide

Thank you again...